# Can I download Image uploads posted along with questions?

Tags: discussion

I want to use a image from [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64747/feedback-required-on-iconography-with-labels-for-payment-method), and then use it in commercial project for showing available payments methods.

Can I? Or is it not allowed?

Comment: After posting this question , in footer i just read user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) , so it means we can.

Comment: ... If you provide attribution ...